# 来年卒業の際に日本へ行ってSierに就職したいなら

Tags: php, java, mysql, oracle

Sierに就職したい理由はweb系とかにより採用されやすいと思います．．．
そのため学ぶべきことはなにか？何の言語 何のフレーム 何のデータベース．．．
本当に迷います 自分はPHPとMySQLを学ぶたいけど でもSierはほとんどOracleを使いらしい．．．
ではPHPの求人が多いですか？Javaの求人が1番多いって知ってますが．．．
アドバイスをください お願いします

Comment: こちらはプログラミングに関するQ&Aを取り扱うサイトで、ITなんでも相談サイトではありません。より適切なサイトを探して相談してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflowの範囲外の質問なので、クローズすべきではあると思いますが、参考までに回答します。

SIerに就職したいとのことですが、SIerの仕事は人、時間、お金の管理なので、就職の際にプログラミングスキルが重視されることはないと思います。就職してから、プログラミングスキルを身につけることや技術的な仕事をやるのは難しいと考えた方がいいです。

海外の大学で勉強されていたのであれば、いろいろな企業が欲しがる人材だと思います。小さくて、無名の企業でも好条件を提示してくるところは多いので、SIerにこだわらず、いろいろな企業を調べてみるといいと思います。

ちなみに、現在の求人の数は、Javaが一番多いと思いますが、将来もそうあり続けるとは言えないと思います。これから何を学ぶべきか迷っているなら、Google Trendsなどで知らべてみるといいかもしれません。